# VB6- FileLen does not return correct value

Tags: vb6

I'm taking over an old code in VB6.

To improve robustness, I've added a test on filesize before reading it.

```
length = FileLen("c:\Program Files (x86)\xxxx\file.ini")
```

Obviously the file does exist, otherwise I wouldn't ask in the forum.

When running code on Windows XP, works fine.
When running code under Windows 10 `length=0`.

Any clue ?

Comment: I don't have a solution but can confirm it isn't a general issue with Windows 10. I have a Windows 10 environment with VB6 and tested the FileLen function with a few INI files on the machine (in Windows folder and Program Files) and it was able to return the correct size.

Comment: It should work; it sounds like a permission issue. What about other files in _C:\Program Files (x86)_ folder, does _FileLen_ work?

Comment: changed permission to total access ... same problem.

Comment: Ran the application 'as admin', it works. So indeed a permission issue as it looks, just need to find out how to set them properly.

Comment: Users don't have write rights to Program Files folders. Changing permissions is a security hole. Ini files go into ProgramData (for system wide settings) or AppData for user settings.

Comment: Assuming that is a normal Windows INI file, it might not matter if the file does not exist. If the file (or a particular setting) does not exist, the code to read a setting will work without errors and will return a default value. Code to write a setting will create the file automatically if it does not exist. I always advise care when modifying old code bases to improve robustness - I've seen people actually reduce robustness because they introduced new bugs into old code that they didn't fully understand, with the best of intentions and thinking they were improving things.

Answer (score 0):

Moved all the code out of `Program Files (x86)` works fine

Comment: That's not really a "fix" even if it bypasses the issue for you.  You have two problems here.  Major one is you seem to be unaware of the implications of UAC which was introduced in 2006!  Minor one is you seem unaware of WOW64 redirection: you should be looking at `Program Files` and you should be locating that either via `App.Path` or a Shell32 special folder query call.  Ideally you'd be using `ProgramData` though and finding that via a Shell call as well.

Comment: You are right I'm not fully aware of these UAC & WOW64 implications, but my code is very old and very unrobust. It is actually using a localdir variable which is pointing to `Program Files (x86)`, this why the fix is good enough for me. But I will research on your indications. Thx